# Bundling browserified libraries

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm having problems finding a canonical approach to building apps with cascading browserified dependencies. I've got a dependency chart that looks something like this:

```
angular  --> lib 1 --> lib 2 --> application
```

Both libraries and the app are CommonJS Angular modules. I'd like to bundle each library separately so they can be used independently and/or in non-CJS apps. When I bundle the app, I want to include all upstream deps (angular, lib1, lib2, etc) in a single vendors.js and the application into a bundle.js.
I've tried using browserify and browserify-shim to create the bundles, but I continually hit a wall where the re-browserified libraries in `vendors.js` cannot locate the modules loaded within.

This doesn't seem like an un-common use case, but I'm having a heck of a time finding any guidance; any advice would be golden. Here's a more concrete example:

Resources Library:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular'); // Non CJS lib; use browserify-shim
require('angular-resource');      // Non CJS lib; use browserify-shim

module.exports = angular.module('resources-library', ['angular-resource']);

require('./services/anApiConsumerResource');
require('./services/anotherApiConsumerResource');
```

Widgets Library:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular'); // Non CJS libs; use browserify-shim
require('resources-library')      // browserified CJS Lib; ??? ??? ???

module.exports = angular.module('widgets-library', ['resources-library']);

require('./directives/someDirectiveThatUsesTheResourceLib');
require('./directives/anotherDirectiveThatUsesTheResourceLib');
```

Sample Application:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular'); // Non CJS libs; use browserify-shim
require('resources-library')      // browserified CJS Lib; ??? ??? ???
require('widgets-library')        // browserified CJS Lib that depends on
                                  // another browserified CJS Lib

module.exports = angular.module('the-best-app-in-the-universe', [
    'resources-library',
    'widgets-library']);

require('./directives/someDirectiveThatUsesTheWidgetsLib');
require('./services/aServiceThatConsumesTheResourceLib');
```

Comment: This is part of the reason why I stopped using Angular earlier on. Angular tries to be too much, particularly in trying to implement its own module system rather than just using something like CommonJS. If you're not tied down to Angular I would highly recommend React.js as an excellent alternative.

Comment: Is their an issue with the file paths? Also, for the other comment, this does not appear to be specifically an angular problem, more browserify and its not recommended to replace a framework (i.e. angular) with a library (e.g. react, jquery, knockout, ...)

Comment: I don't think so. Individually, I can browserify each library, plop them in a script tag in a test page, and they work. The problem arises when I attempt to bundle the browserified scripts downstream (e.g. when I bundle angular+resources-library together in widgets or app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 7/2017**
Use [Gulp-Derequire](https://github.com/twada/gulp-derequire).

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    var bundleStream = browserify({entries: './index.js', standalone: 'yourModule'}).bundle();
    return bundleStream
        .pipe(source('yourModule.js'))
        .pipe(derequire())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

Thanks to @Michael Heuberger for [identifying this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45127167/1424869).

**Original Answer 9/2014**

I believe the correct answer here is to *not* browserify distributed libraries. We simply concatenate and minify all libraries - including the ones we built using browserify - and everything starts to come together nicely.