# How to investigate "Cannot find module X" coming from browserified bundles?

Tags: gulp, babeljs, browserify

I tried many different configs and all failed. I have a browserified + babelified bundle called videomail-client.js here:

https://github.com/binarykitchen/videomail-client/tree/develop/dist

The package.json's main entry of that package is pointing to this file.

Now, when I `require()` that package from another project within and browserify it, then I see this error from the gulp task using browserify:

```
[16:26:32] Error: Cannot find module './keys' from '/home/michael-heuberger/code/videomail.io/node_modules/videomail-client/dist'
    at /home/michael-heuberger/code/videomail.io/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
    at load (/home/michael-heuberger/code/videomail.io/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/home/michael-heuberger/code/videomail.io/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /home/michael-heuberger/code/videomail.io/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

If this sounds complicated, let me rephrase. Package videomail-client is browserified. Another project, videomail.io, is requiring it and browserifying all together over again with other packages. That's there it fails.

On a side note, when I run stand-alone examples using videomail-client.js, it works fine.

I think the problem is that browserify can't resolve the `./keys` file. But it should be included in the browserified videomail-client.js package and resolved from there. How can I tell browserify to resolve it the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

The solution has two steps: use browserify's standalone option and the [gulp-derequire](https://github.com/twada/gulp-derequire) package. It works now.

Comment: Nice! Would you mind posting the solution (sample code) and accepting your answer? If you get sample code in there I'll link from my old post too; this'll help the next poor sap who runs into this issue. :)

Comment: dont have enough rep to accept my own answer :) ... and the working solution is already out on github here https://github.com/binarykitchen/videomail-client/blob/develop/gulpfile.js#L83

Answer (score 0):

This sounds *a lot* like a problem I [ran into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876063/bundling-browserified-libraries) a few years ago (and yes, it is tough to describe :) )

I never got an answer but maybe you'll have better luck. The solution I eventually went with was to *not* attempt to re-browserify already-browserified libraries; I ended up just concatenating it in and minifying the whole bundle afterwards.

Comment: ...or switch to WebPack, if that's an option. It's a much more versatile bundler, in my experience.

Comment: mmmhhh, thanks but don't want to give up here. but maybe i should consider using the unbrowserified source code of the videomail-client package itself. but then, the problem is that, it's written in ES6 and any other project requiring it must babelify it first which is cumbersome ...

Comment: Actually, that's not as far fetched as you might think. ES6+ projects can ref the source, and ES5 projects can include the browserified lib. That's becoming accepted / standard practice (ref [rollup js](https://github.com/rollup/rollup#publishing-es6-modules)) and the afore-mentioned WebPack).

Comment: yeah thanks, but still ES5 projects wouldn't be able to browserify themselves including already browserified npm packages.

Comment: True. I don't think Browserify is designed for that use case; I can't find it now but when I ping'd the authors their response was along the lines of "why would you want to do that?" If you are able to make it work please post your solution; I'd like to see it. Good luck!